# How to change username/password in TortoiseCVS

Tags: authentication, tortoisecvs

Previously I had no username and password for my local Tortoise CVS repository. I used another one's. Now I have a username and password for me.

How do I get TortoiseCVS to let me enter the new username/password?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Go to first CVS folder, open Root file and add the user@ before the domain.

For example:

```
:pserver:yourcvsServer:/cvsroot/public
```

should be changed with:

```
:pserver:yourUsername@yourcvsServer:/cvsroot/public
```